# JQuery Issue when creating sliding side menu

Tags: jquery, css, accordion

Supposed to:

1. Click header in menu
2. All sections slide up
3. The clicked section slides down

What happens:

1. Click header in menu
2. All sections slide up
3. The clicked section slides down
4. All sections slide down !!

How can I keep the clicked section open?

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
        //slide up all the link lists
        $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
        //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        } 
    })
})
```

CSS:

```
/*custom font for text*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);

/*Basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    background: #4EB889;
    font-family: Nunito, arial, verdana;
}
#accordian {
    background: #004050;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    color: white;
    /*Some cool shadow and glow effect*/
    box-shadow: 
        0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
        0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
/*heading styles*/
#accordian h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 34px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
    background: #003040; 
    /*background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);*/
    @include linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
}
/*heading hover effect*/
#accordian h3:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
/*iconfont styles*/
#accordian h3 span {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
/*list items*/
#accordian li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*links*/
#accordian ul ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
/*hover effect on links*/
#accordian ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #003545;
    border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;
}
/*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
#accordian ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#accordian li.active ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS isn't that important. Your HTML is. Please show it. Also, "accordion".

Comment: Seems to work fine without your CSS. No need for the if statement--jQuery handles that for you. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ZAutZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is with your CSS (and your misspelling of "accordion") and my best guess at your HTML. It seems to work fine with one small modification. I've added the `not()` method to filter the current child list. Again, there's no need for the if statement checking visibility.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ZAutZ/2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
        // slide up all the link lists
        $("#accordian ul ul").not( $(this).next() ).slideUp();
        // slide down this one
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    })
})
```